# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в AlertDialog он не закрывался?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть AlertDialog с EditText. В случае, если текст, введеный пользователем окажется пустой строкой, нужно чтобы показывался toast и диалог не закрывался, а закрывался в случае, если строка не пустая или при нажатии кнопки Cancel.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_layout, null)
        val editText = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text)
        with(builder) {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.enter_name_for_new_list))
            setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, which ->
                val text = editText.text.toString()
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    showMessage(getString(R.string.enter_list_name))
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null)
            setView(dialogLayout)
            show()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут не сложно, нужно переопределить результат нажатия на кнопки

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.task_edit, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialog);
    mDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    mDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(_title,
                    (dialog, id) -> {
                    // пусто!
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.diag12,
                    (dialog, id) -> {
                    // пусто!
                    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // делаете проверку, если всё хорошо, то...
        if (_check_right()) {
            // ...делаете обработку и закрываете диалог
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Аналогично с двумя типа других кнопок. Я написал на Java, переделать на kotlin не сложно, Студио сам переконвертирует

Comment: Ещё можно не использовать кнопки диалога, а добавить свои в макет.

Comment: Тоже можно, не пробовал