# Как не дать закрыться AlertDialog при нажатии на PositiveButton по условию

Tags: java, android

При попытке обработать нажатия кнопки "Регистрация" в AlertDialog не могу не дать закрыться окну.
Не важно какую кнопку нажимаешь отмена или регистрация, окно диалога все равно закрывается.
Как предотвратить закрытие окна по условию.

```
    public void showRegisterWindow(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View regWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_form, null);
        final TextInputEditText userName = regWindow.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        final TextInputEditText phone = regWindow.findViewById(R.id.phone);

        dialog.setTitle("Авторизация телефона")
            .setMessage("Введите данные для регистрации")
            .setView(regWindow)
            .setPositiveButton("Регистрация", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Введите имя", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                // чик-чик код
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", (dialogInterface, id) -> dialogInterface.dismiss())
            .create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Даже если вместо обработчика кнопки ставить null все равно закрывается.

Comment: Стандартные кнопки всегда закрывают диалоговое окно. Вам нужно использовать свою разметку в которой сделаете свои кнопки и обработчики на них. [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352324)

Comment: Вот решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-alertdialog-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f?rq=1

Comment: Arty Morris, спасибо. Сделал как описано там, все заработало как нужно. Style-7, так и есть сам не нашел эту ветку, Arty Morris помог.

Answer (score 0):

Благодоря Arty Morris в соседней [ветке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374583/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-alertdialog-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F?rq=1) переделал код:

```
public void showRegisterWindow(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View regWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_form, null);
    final TextInputEditText userName = regWindow.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    final TextInputEditText phone = regWindow.findViewById(R.id.phone);

    dialog.setTitle("Авторизация телефона")
        .setMessage("Введите данные для регистрации")
        .setView(regWindow)
        .setPositiveButton("Регистрация", null)
        .setNegativeButton("Отмена", null);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName.getText())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите имя", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            String userString = Objects.requireNonNull(userName.getText()).toString();
            String phoneString = Objects.requireNonNull(phone.getText()).toString();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            registerUser(userString,phoneString);
        }
    });
}
```